docker-compose upで "bundler: command not found: rails" というエラーになる
ubuntu内にdockerでrails環境構築しようとしています。
appディレクトリで実装を進めていく予定ですが、まずは環境を用意したく最小構成で始めています。
docker-compose buildは問題なく完了します。
次にdocker-compose upを実行すると、以下のようなエラーで起動に失敗してしまいます。
demo_api  | bundler: command not found: rails
demo_api  | Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
demo_api exited with code 127

自分の認識ではDockerfileのRUN bundle installでrailsがインストールされている想定だったのですが、違うのでしょうか。
dockerは勉強しながら進めている状態のため、至らない部分がありましたら申し訳ありません。
ディレクトリ構成
demo/
 ├ app/
 │  ├ Gemfile
 │  └ Gemfile.lock
 ├ docker-compose.yml
 ├ Dockerfile
 └ entrypoint.sh

Gemfile:
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '7.1.3'

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    container_name: "demo_api"
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ./gem_cache:/app/vendor/bundle
    ports:
      - "4010:4010"
    command: /bin/sh -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 4010 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    networks:
      demo-networks:
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
  db:
    container_name: "demo_db"
    image: mysql:8
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=demo_development
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      demo-networks:
networks:
  demo-networks:

Dockerfile
FROM ruby:3.3.1

ENV BUNDLE_PATH /app/vendor/bundle
ENV APP_HOME /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https vim

RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY app .

RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle config set --local path $BUNDLE_PATH

RUN bundle install

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 3306

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

